# Library book sorting

Tags: java

I am in a java programming class and I cannot figure how to fix this error.

This is the error I keep getting:

Library.java:120: error: class, interface, or enum expected
import java.util.ArrayList;
^
1 error

This is the task

Two sorted lists have been created, one implemented using a linked list (`LinkedListLibrary linkedListLibrary`) and the other implemented using the built-in ArrayList class (`ArrayListLibrary arrayListLibrary`). Each list contains 100 books (title, ISBN number, author), sorted in ascending order by ISBN number.

Complete main() by inserting a new book into each list using the respective `LinkedListLibrary` and `ArrayListLibrary` insertSorted() methods and outputting the number of operations the computer must perform to insert the new book. Each insertSorted() returns the number of operations the computer performs.

Ex: If the input is:

```
The Catcher in the Rye
9787543321724
J.D. Salinger
```

the output is:

```
Number of linked list operations: 1
Number of ArrayList operations: 1
```

This is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
public class Library {
public static void fillLibraries(LinkedListLibrary linkedListLibrary, ArrayListLibrary arrayListLibrary) throws IOException {
   FileInputStream fileByteStream = null; // File input stream
   Scanner inFS = null; // Scanner object
   int linkedListOperations = 0;
   int arrayListOperations = 0;    
  
   BookNode currNode;
   Book tempBook;

   String bookTitle;
   String bookAuthor;
   long bookISBN;
  
   // Try to open file
   fileByteStream = new FileInputStream("Books.txt");
   inFS = new Scanner(fileByteStream);

   while (inFS.hasNextLine()) {
       bookTitle = inFS.nextLine();
       bookISBN = inFS.nextLong();
       inFS.nextLine();
       bookAuthor = inFS.nextLine();

       // Insert into linked list
       currNode = new BookNode(bookTitle, bookAuthor, bookISBN);
       linkedListOperations = linkedListLibrary.insertSorted(currNode, linkedListOperations);
       linkedListLibrary.lastNode = currNode;

       // Insert into ArrayList
       tempBook = new Book(bookTitle, bookAuthor, bookISBN);
       arrayListOperations = arrayListLibrary.insertSorted(tempBook, arrayListOperations);
   }
  
   fileByteStream.close(); // close() may throw IOException if fails
   }

   public static void main (String[] args) throws IOException {
       Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
       int linkedListOperations = 0;
       int arrayListOperations = 0;
  
       // Create libraries
       LinkedListLibrary linkedListLibrary = new LinkedListLibrary();
       ArrayListLibrary arrayListLibrary = new ArrayListLibrary();
  
       // Fill libraries with 100 books
       fillLibraries(linkedListLibrary, arrayListLibrary);
  
       // Create new book to insert into libraries
       BookNode currNode;
       Book tempBook;
  
       String bookTitle;
       String bookAuthor;
       long bookISBN;
  
       bookTitle = scnr.nextLine();
       bookISBN = scnr.nextLong();
       scnr.nextLine();
       bookAuthor = scnr.nextLine();

       // Insert into linked list
       currNode = new BookNode(bookTitle, bookAuthor, bookISBN);
       // TODO
       int i = linkedListLibrary.insertSorted(currNode,0);
  
       linkedListLibrary.lastNode = currNode;
  
       // Insert into ArrayList
       tempBook = new Book(bookTitle, bookAuthor, bookISBN);
       // TODO
       int j = arrayListLibrary.insertSorted(tempBook,0);
  
       // TODO: Print number of operations for linked list
       System.out.println("Number of operations for linked list : "+i);
       // TODO: Print number of operations for ArrayList
       System.out.println("Number of operations for ArrayList : "+j);
   }
}

// Book.java

public class Book{

   private String bookTitle;
   private String bookAuthor;
   private long bookISBN;

   public Book() {
       bookTitle = "";
       bookAuthor = "";
       bookISBN = 0;
   }

   public Book(String userBookTitle, String userBookAuthor, long userBookISBN) {
       bookTitle = userBookTitle;
       bookAuthor = userBookAuthor;
       bookISBN = userBookISBN;
   }
  
   public long getBookISBN() {
       return bookISBN;
   }
  
   public void printInfo(){
       System.out.println("Title: " + bookTitle);
       System.out.println("Author: " + bookAuthor);
       System.out.println("ISBN: " + bookISBN);
   }
}

// ArrayListLibrary.java

import java.util.ArrayList;
public class ArrayListLibrary {
   // ArraryList library
   public ArrayList<Book> library;

   public ArrayListLibrary() {
       library = new ArrayList<Book>();
   }
   public int insertSorted(Book newBook, int counter) {
       Book currBook;
       // Add an empty element at end of list
       library.add(null);
       // Loop through elements starting at the end
       for (int i = library.size() - 2; i >=0; --i) {
           currBook = library.get(i);

           // If the current book's ISBN is larger than newBook's ISBN, shift
           // the current book down 1, count shift operation
           if(currBook.getBookISBN() > newBook.getBookISBN()){
               library.set(i+1, currBook);
               ++counter;
           }
  
           // Otherwise, place newBook at the next location (empty slot),
           // count insert operation
           else {
               library.set(i+1, newBook);
               ++counter;
               return counter;
           }
       }
       // If we get to the top of the list, place newBook on top
       library.set(0, newBook);
       ++counter;
  
       return counter;
   }
  
   public void printLibrary() {
       for (int i = 0; i < library.size(); ++i) {
           library.get(i).printInfo();
           System.out.println();
       }
   }
}

// BookNode.java

public class BookNode {
   private String bookTitle;
   private String bookAuthor;
   private long bookISBN;
   private BookNode nextNodePtr; // Reference to the next node   
   public BookNode() {
       bookTitle = "";
       bookAuthor = "";
       bookISBN = 0;
       nextNodePtr = null;
   }
   // Constructor   
   public BookNode(String bookTitleInit, String bookAuthorInit, long bookISBNInit) {
       this.bookTitle = bookTitleInit;
       this.bookAuthor = bookAuthorInit;
       this.bookISBN = bookISBNInit;
       this.nextNodePtr = null;
   }
   // Constructor   
   public BookNode(String bookTitleInit, String bookAuthorInit, long bookISBNInit, BookNode nextLoc) {
       this.bookTitle = bookTitleInit;
       this.bookAuthor = bookAuthorInit;
       this.bookISBN = bookISBNInit;
       this.nextNodePtr = nextLoc;
   }
   // insertAfter
   public void insertAfter(BookNode nodeLoc) {
       BookNode tmpNext;

       tmpNext = this.nextNodePtr;
       this.nextNodePtr = nodeLoc;
       nodeLoc.nextNodePtr = tmpNext;
   }
   //setNext
   public void setNext(BookNode nodeLoc) {
       this.nextNodePtr = nodeLoc;
   }
   // Get location pointed by nextNodePtr   
   public BookNode getNext() {
       return this.nextNodePtr;
   }
   public long getBookISBN() {
       return this.bookISBN;
   }
   // TODO: Print book information
   public void printBookInfo() {
       System.out.println("Title: " + this.bookTitle);
       System.out.println("Author: " + this.bookAuthor);
       System.out.println("ISBN: " + this.bookISBN);
   }
}

// LinkedListLibrary.java

public class LinkedListLibrary {
   //Linked list nodes
   BookNode headNode;
   BookNode lastNode;

   LinkedListLibrary() {
       // Front of nodes list   
       headNode = new BookNode();
       lastNode = headNode;
   }

   public int insertSorted(BookNode newNode, int counter) {
       BookNode currNode, nextNode;
  
       // Special case for head node
       if (headNode == null || headNode.getBookISBN() >= newNode.getBookISBN()) {
           newNode.insertAfter(headNode);
           headNode = newNode;
       }
       else {
           // Locate the node before insertion point
           currNode = headNode;
  
           while (currNode.getNext() != null && currNode.getNext().getBookISBN() < newNode.getBookISBN()) {
               currNode = currNode.getNext();
           }
           newNode.setNext(currNode.getNext());
           currNode.insertAfter(newNode);
       }
  
       ++counter;
       return counter;
   }

   public void printLibrary() {
       BookNode currNode;

       currNode = headNode.getNext();
       while (currNode != null) {
           currNode.printBookInfo();
           System.out.println();
           currNode = currNode.getNext();
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: Is all of this code in one file?

Comment: Not a file. It's in a like assignment on Zybooks. Some of the code is already included in the assignment and we have to modify it with the prompt.

Answer (score 2):

Did the same lab. They make it seem intimidating with the amount of files and text thrown at you, but to pass the lab you just need to add the two lines to the end of Library.java:

```
  System.out.println("Number of linked list operations: " + linkedListLibrary.insertSorted(currNode, linkedListOperations));
  System.out.println("Number of ArrayList operations: " + arrayListLibrary.insertSorted(tempBook, arrayListOperations));
```

To explain:
The lab was to help you go through established code and read its set methods to learn how to do work in a class you haven't made. If you followed the development stubs (#TODO's) you would trace the path to finding what you need to do. This is what leads to the solution in this case!